# Is there a built-in pipe to show only part of entries in an array

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I'm showing products:

```
<li *ngFor="let product of products">{{product.id}}</li>
```

I want to limit the number of entries shown using the property on component. Is there a built-in pipe to do that or I should create my own pipe?

Here is how I see it:

```
<li *ngFor="let product of products | length[propertyOnComponent]">{{product.id}}</li>
```

So, if `propertyOnComponent` is 3, then only 3 entries will be shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `slice` in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

```
<li *ngFor="let product of products | slice:0:propertyOnComponent">{{product.id}}</li>
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way to implement this is to  use the [slice pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/SlicePipe-pipe.html) with *start* and *end* parameter.

```
<li *ngFor="let product of products | slice:0:propertyOnComponent">
  {{product.id}}
</li>
```